# What is a 'borrowed flesh"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've just stumbled upon this phrase and found no direct translation or definition, so it must be a metaphor. Can anyone try to explain it? The source is *Naked Lunch* by W.S. Burroughs.

> I awoke from the Sickness at the age of forty-five, calm and sane, and in reasonably good health except for a weakened liver and the look of borrowed flesh common to all who survive the Sickness.

Comment: There is a reference to **borrowed flesh** in *Strange Histories: The Trial of the Pig, the Walking Dead, and Other Matters* by Darren Oldridge, which uses the phrase in relation to devils using the 'bodies of the dead'. "By appearing in the **borrowed flesh** of 'stinking corpses', demons were..." So perhaps here, the idea is as though the narrator's body, after the ravages of the Sickness, does not appear to be his own, but that of a corpse or a cadaver.

Comment: A quick Google Book Search reveals that it's an old concept that dates at least from the time of  St. Augustine (born  354 A.D., died 430 A.D.).  Here are a couple of links. https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DnHYCARoACgC&pg=PA426&dq=borrowed+flesh&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-1Kn8yJrqAhWVo3EKHQ7xAesQuwUwAXoECAMQBw#v=onepage&q=borrowed%20flesh&f=false .......  https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=borrowed+flesh

Comment: "I awoke from the Sickness" = I stopped being an addict" - "I awoke from the Sickness [with] the look of borrowed flesh.." should be understood as "I awoke from the Sickness and, to me, my skin and body looked as if it were not mine." Burroughs had spent a long time as an addict and his skin had developed a pallour common to drug addicts.

Comment: I think the exact "meaning" here is a matter of Off-Topic (POB) "literary interpretation" rather than the use of English as such. My opinion - it's an allusion to / riffing off ***living on borrowed time***. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: I thank all of you. But I seem to have insufficient reputation to chose an answer and close the topic.